# REST services basic auth session timeout

Tags: rest, session, web.xml, basic-authentication

I'm working on a restful webservice using basic authentication. In the web xml I have the following:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This works as expected: the user must supply a password when interacting with the service.

However, to conform the more RESTful standards, I think it really should be a stateless service where the session is never created. In other words, I would like to force the clients to supply their credentials for each request.

If I set the session-timeout to 0 in the web-xml, this is interpreted as "never expire", which is the exact opposite of what I want.

Is there a simple way to get the session to get invalidated immediately?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the <session-config> element at all.

What you experience is how browsers implement the authentication protocol.

Briefly the basic authentication (rfc 2617) works like this:

1. Client requests some resource.
2. Server recognizes that the resource has a security constraint. Therefore it sends a HTTP 401 "Authorization required" response. The header contains something like...

   ```
   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected"
   ```
3. The client resends its request, but this time with the credentials (base64-encoded) in the header, e.g. ...

   ```
   Authorization: Basic dG9tY2F0OnMzY3JIdA==
   ```
4. The server authenticates the request based on the given credentials and sends the requested resource.

In order to make web browsing convenient for humans virtually every browser caches the credentials until the browser is closed. Every time you reload the page in the browser the "Authorization" entry is sent with the header of the request. Therefore you are not asked for your credentials again while testing your web service with a browser.

With Firefox you can control that behavior. Check out the discussion about [Firefox quickly forget HTTP Basic Auth](https://superuser.com/questions/181547/firefox-quickly-forget-http-basic-auth).

Comment: This is configured as a cookie which makes it possible for the user to browse without supplying the credentials for every request. You are able to specify for how long this cookie/session should be valid.