# How to expire Authorization header in request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, basic-authentication

I've tried to understand and implement the Basic Authentication algorithm, and [looks like it works as expected](http://parzh--basic-auth-triage-app.herokuapp.com/). Now I have a problem: the `Authorization` header in the request never expires (at least, it hasn't for a couple of days now), so the client always sees the protected content, whereas I want them to re-authenticate every minute.

Judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367721/4554883), the problem is that this is basically how browsers work, – they remember user credentials for convenience. Alas, the answer does not provide any solution, only an explanation, and I would really love to not rely on client browser settings.

**What can I add on the server so that the `Authorization` header in the request, once created, expires after 1 minute, and isn't included in the requests sent 1 minute later?**

---

I'm using `express` lib for the server and `express-session` for cookies (see the code of actual authentication middleware below). The cookies are set to have `Max-Age` of 60 seconds:

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60_000,
    },
}));
```

The `GET /private` request needs to have the correct `Authorization` header to reach to the content. The problem with the approach below is that while `req.session.authenticated` is `undefined` after 1 minute (cookie session expired), the `req.get("Authorization")` is still present (neither `null`, nor `undefined`), and is correct, so the server automatically authenticates client again:

```js
app.route("/private").get(
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.session.authenticated) {
            const authorization = req.get("Authorization");

            if (authorization == null)
                return authenticate(res); // see function definition below

            const [ , credentialsRaw ] = authorization.split(" ");
            const [ username, password ] = Buffer.from(credentialsRaw, "base64").toString("ascii").split(":");

            if (username in users === false)
                return authenticate(res);

            if (password !== users[username].password) // I didn't bother with security
                return authenticate(res);

            req.session.authenticated = true;
        }

        next();
    },
    (req, res) => {
        res.send(`<h1>Congratulations! You've accessed the private page! </h1>`);
    },
);
```

```js
function authenticate(res) {
    res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Access to the staging site"`);
    res.status(401).send(`<h1>Unauthorized !</h1>`)
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You should consider token based authorization where the expiration date is included in the token itself.

Comment: With basic auth, it will be just a user/pwd combo. so if the password is correct the api will work. You can create a JWT token with expiry value/creation time set and validate the token for every request. You can verify the signature of the JWT to ensure that is not forged or tampered. With a very short expiry duration you can prevent replay attack as well. For a longer expiry you would need to devise other ways. [https://jwt.io/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like HTTP Basic Authentication does not include logging out or expiring the credentials.

<sup>If anybody wants my opinion, it's a shame, actually.</sup>